# Titanium : Unable to download module from the specified URL. Is the URL valid?

Tags: paypal, titanium, titanium-alloy, titanium-modules

Titanium version - 3.2.2

Alloy project.

I need to implement PayPal library into the app.

I download all the library from [here](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_modules)

But when I install them on the OS Maverics, I get the "Unable to download module from the specified URL. Is URL valid ? "

Can someone help with PayPal library installing ?

I use Help->Install Mobile Module->Titanium SDK for the module installing.

Comment: What's the url you are using?

Comment: zip of the modules is located on my disk, so the URK is the path to the zip of my modules.

Comment: I've added my answer how to install local module. Please update your question and title to better describe problem for people looking for solution to the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install Titanium Module from local disc you have to put it into directory `~/Library/Application Support/Titanium`. Titanium will extract this zip into module directory during next build.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to install a module in Titanium, globally or locally.

If you are using version control, such as git, to share the project repo with other team members, I would recommend installing the module locally to the project. This will ensure that everyone is using the same version of the module to avoid version conflicts. If you are planning to use the module for Android and iOS applications, a seperate module for each platform will need to be installed.

To install the Paypal module locally:

For Android:

1. Go to the [titanium_modules](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_modules) repo located on Github
2. Navigate to titanium_modules / paypal / mobile / android / dist /
3. Click the version of the module you would like to install (at the time of this writing, ti.paypal-anddroid-2.2.3.zip is the only available version for download)
4. Right click on the 'View Raw' link in the middle of the page and click the 'Save link as...' option.
5. Download the .zip file to the root directory of your project. The project root directory is the top directory of your project.

For iOS:

1. Go to the [titanium_modules](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_modules) repo located on Github
2. Navigate to titanium_modules / paypal / mobile / ios /
3. Click the version of the module you would like to install (at the time of this writing, ti.paypal-ios-1.8.0.zip is the only available version for download)
4. Right click on the 'View Raw' link in the middle of the page and click the 'Save link as...' option.
5. Download the .zip file to the root directory of your project

Once the zipped modules are downloaded to the root of the project, the next time the project is compiled, the modules will be extracted and available for use in the project.

After the modules have been extracted, be sure that the modules are selected for use in  tiapp.xml.

Hope this helps! If so, please don't forget to up vote (need rep to perform other functions on SO :)